# Bootstrap 4 : Vertical alignment in responsive table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

With Bootstrap 4, when `table-responsive` is added to the table, the text is no longer center vertically. Is it a bug ? If not, is there a simple solution to get the text centered in the middle. A pure Bootstrap solution will be appreciated.

Here is an illustration of the problem.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

<table class="bg-danger table-responsive" style="width:300px; height:200px;">  
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">
      <div class="text-left">
        table-responsive
      </div>      
    </th>
  </tr>  
</table>

<table class="bg-success " style="width:300px; height:200px;">  
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">
      <div class="text-left">
        no table-responsive
      </div>      
    </th>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but I noticed that the problem comes from the display attribute. It is changed from table to block by the class table-responsive

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `.table-responsive` class to a container element, not the table itself.

[Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/content/tables/#responsive-tables)

> Responsive tables allow tables to be scrolled horizontally with ease. Make any table responsive across all viewports by **wrapping** a .table with .table-responsive. Or, pick a maximum breakpoint with which to have a responsive table up to by using .table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="bg-danger" style="width:300px; height:200px;">  
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <div class="text-left">
          table-responsive
        </div>      
      </th>
    </tr>  
  </table>
</div>
<table class="bg-success " style="width:300px; height:200px;">  
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">
      <div class="text-left">
        no table-responsive
      </div>      
    </th>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

So override bootstrap styles with your styles "display:table":

```
<table class="bg-danger table-responsive" style="width:300px; height:200px; display:table;"> 
...
```

But if you have many text in cell - it will be cut off.
See documentation for responsive tables:

> Vertical clipping/truncation Responsive tables make use of overflow-y:
>   hidden, which clips off any content that goes beyond the bottom or top
>   edges of the table. In particular, this can clip off dropdown menus
>   and other third-party widgets.

Comment: If you add `display:table` to a `table-responsive` table, the table isn't anymore responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set a `height` for the `tbody`, because it has `vertical-align: middle` by default. Therefor you could omit the `height` for the `table`. Furthermore there is no need for inline styles. You can override the bootstrap style by defining `width` for the non-responsive table and `max-width` for the responsive.

**Working example:**

I exchanged the fixed dimensions with responsive ones (for example: `300px` -> `45vw`)

```css
table {
  width: 45vw;
  max-width: 45vw;
}

tbody {
  height: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="bg-danger table-responsive">  
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">
      <div class="text-left">
        table-responsive
      </div>      
    </th>
  </tr>  
</table>

<table class="bg-success">  
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">
      <div class="text-left">
        no table-responsive
      </div>      
    </th>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

In Boostrap 4 table, when the class is `class="table-responsive"`, just add `class="pt-md-3 pt-3"` to the `<td>` element to vertical align its content (plain text, div, ...) respect to the height of its cell, as in this example:

```
<table class="table-responsive">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="pt-md-3 pt-3">Foo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try as the following:

```
.table > tbody > tr > td {
    align-items: center;
}
```

or

```html
<td class="align-center">You</td>
```

Comment: This doesn't work - even if you use the correct selector (`th` instead of `td`)...